# Proving that a set is a vector subspace of a complex vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I would like to solve the following question

W  = { $\left[\begin{array}{cc} a&b\\ c&d \\ \end{array}\right] $ | $ a = \overline{d}$ }

I need to show that

a. W is NOT a complex vector subspace of M$_2(C)$

b. W is a vector subspace of real vector space  M$_2(C)$

I do not understand the difference between the notations of M$_2(C)$ in both the parts because if we are talking about a real vector space then shouldn't it be  M$_2(R)$ in the second part ?

Comment: $M_2(C)$ as a real vector space means that the scalars come from the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every complex vector space is also a real vector space. In particular, ${\rm M}_2(\Bbb C)$. You have to check that $W$ is not closed under multiplication by complex scalar, but it is closed under multiplication by real scalar. So, once you have shown that $W$ is closed under multiplication by real scalar, it suffices to show that if $A \in W$ has $ad\neq 0$, then ${\rm i}A \not\in W$.